# How to ignore spaces in mysqbl column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of artist names such as Lady Gaga, Jason Mraz, Death Cab For Cutie, etc.

I want to be able to search for artists with no spaces.  For instance, search the artists table where name is jasonmraz.

Is there any way to do this with mysql?  Or should I create a new column in my table to hold these types of names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(your_col, " ", "") ...
```

or

```
SELECT your_col
WHERE REPLACE(your_col, " ", "") = "somestringsansspaces"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REPLACE function

```
SELECT REPLACE('Lady Gaga', ' ', '');
```

Will return LadyGaga

Answer (score 0):

Using `REPLACE()`, as suggested, will work.
Bear in mind, however, that this is more work for your server, so if you have a large table of names (which I doubt you do, but never mind) you might want to consider adding a field of the names with no spaces.

Comment: I hear this argument a lot, but lately my experiences with high volume database access has led me to doubt it. String functions don't offer a whole lot of overhead and I've never seen any significant slowdown (though, I suppose in the extremes it'll always exist, millions of records and so forth) but at the same time imagine the search overhead of millions of extra field entries. I'm not sure which the lesser evil would be. Would be fun to test!

Comment: Though this would go against the general idea "don't store what you can compute" which I think would be better practice here. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/20/327369.aspx)  Replace has computational costs involved, but I **speculate** that those costs are outweighed by the adjustment in schema, data redundancy/ space overhead and query tweaks.

Comment: my artists table is 110,218 rows.. so yeah

Comment: If you index, the search overhead shouldn't increase no matter how many fields you have. Speaking of indexing, you wouldn't be able to have one without that additional field, would you?
While I am a fan of "don't store what you can compute" I'm learning the hard way (now our software is running huge numbers) that denormalisation is your friend.

Comment: Well, won't increase much, but will still increase. An index is just a separated space on disk that contains only records of the indexed data and a pointer to the original row that it comes from. It uses a hell of a lot less reads to parse, but it does certainly still have associated overhead. Plus an extra amount of space on disk (from record and index files)